# Paper.js with excanvas

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, excanvas, paperjs

I've grown to like paper.js a lot but after realizing that it does not support IE8, I was wondering if it was possible to have paper.js working together with excanvas? Has anyone tested this and are there examples available?

Thank you.

Comment: I've not been able to find anybody who has written a fix to support IE. I think the paper.js website also says it won't support IE somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Paper.js code explicitly uses HTMLCanvasElement (line 7137 in [dist as of 8/11/12](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/master/dist/paper.js#L7137)), which does not exist on IE8, so out of the box the code fails.

The paperjs [About page](http://paperjs.org/about/) says:

> Paper.js is aimed at modern browsers with support for the Canvas
>   object and EcmaScript 5. Even though in theory it is possible to write
>   code that works in older browsers (Yes Explorer 8 and below, we are
>   looking at you!), we currently do not support them out of the box.
>   Let’s go forward!

It may be possible to modify the paperjs code to get it working, but I failed to do so (testing in IETester...with the error that the canvas did not have a getContext property even though excanvas should have provided one).